# dpkg and missing dependency problem

Tags: apt, unity-dash, dpkg, dependencies, deb

I downloaded an open source software from the Internet to emulate white board on my computer. The link is here: http://open-sankore.org/
The download was as `.zip` file with `.deb` file inside (which I presume is the installation file)

I navigated to the directory where the `.deb` file is and I used the command:

```
dpkg -i {filename.deb}
```

However, the log says that there are some unmet dependencies. The icon of OpenSankure does show up Dash but when I open Software Center, it says that the software catalog is broken and needs to be repaired.
After repair, OpenSankure disappears from Dash.

**Can someone tell me how i can ensure that all dependencies are met at the time of install ?**

```
Selecting previously unselected package open-sankore:i386.
(Reading database ... 178700 files and directories currently installed.)
Unpacking open-sankore:i386 (from Open-Sankore_2.1.0_i386.deb) ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of open-sankore:i386:
 open-sankore:i386 depends on libpaper1 (>= 1.1.24+nmu1build1).
dpkg: error processing open-sankore:i386 (--install):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils ...
Processing triggers for bamfdaemon ...
Rebuilding /usr/share/applications/bamf.index...
Processing triggers for gnome-menus ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 open-sankore:i386
```

Comment: Did you install the 32bit version on a 64bit Ubuntu? I've just installed the 64bit on 64bit and it worked fine.

Comment: @Oli I have 32 bit version and tried to install 32 bit version of OpenSankure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be sure that all the dependencies of a software will be met, you should install it using the Ubuntu Software Centre or `apt-get`. However, I understand that sometimes you need to download software from other sources. In that case sometimes dependencies are not met. To fix this, download a graphical `.deb` installer called GDebi. It will download all the necessary dependencies, if any, at the time of installtion.

Comment: Didnt work. Still says it needs some `libpaper1`

Comment: Download `Synaptic Package Manager`. Then search for and install `libpaper1`. If `libpaper1` depends on other softwares, Synaptic will ask you to download them too. Personally I like Synaptic better than Ubuntu Software Centre. It's easier to find the software you're looking for. You can even make a script in Synaptic, so that you can download a software (and its dependencies) to another computer and bring them back to yours.

Comment: So if I have synaptic, GDebi is useless. I can uninstall it ?

Comment: Ya, sure. You can uninstall GDebi.

Answer (score 1):

Try with:

> `sudo apt-get install -f`

After these dependecies are fixed, try with

> `sudo dpkg -i {filename.deb}`

Comment: The first command (`apt-get …`) should be enough to resolve missing dependencies and configure unconfigured packages. The second command will just re-install the package. If any, the commands should be issued in reverse order.

Comment: I had the same issue while running "dpkg --configure -a" 
The first command ("sudo apt-get install -f") worked for me.
Thanks